# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer file not found

Tags: spring, jboss7.x, war

I am trying to use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with an external properties file, one that is not part of the WAR file.

I configured the bean as follows:

```
<property name="location" value="${jboss.server.data.dir}/my-dir/common.properties"/>
```

When the WAR file was deployed, I got an error message:

.....
Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/C:/dir/jboss-as-7.1.1.Test/standalone/data/my-dir/common.properties]

Any way that I can place the properties file outside the WAR file?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, but use the value classpath:common.properties. Just ensure that is in the classpath somewhere.

```
<property name="location" value="classpath:common.properties"/>
```

You can also use the file: to get this to work if it is not on the classpath.

```
<property name="location" value="file:${jboss.server.data.dir}/my-dir/common.properties"/>
```